# Issues with whmcs and my Javascript files

Tags: javascript, html, whmcs

So I have got my own javascript file for a hover over login box at the top of my website. And im using WHMCS for the billing and ordering end. Whmcs uses a Jquery library they heavily edited. And removing it breaks the navbar and everything else including the domain name order forms.

Here is my JS file that is needed for the hover login box to work - http://pastebin.com/hGH93abr

And here is WHMCS's Jquery js file - http://pastebin.com/jdZ1676e

Now I have removed the Jquery.js for whmcs and replaced it with my js file. And then the hover over login box works perfect, yet everything on whmcs just breaks, or refuses to work anymore. I tried jquery no conflict mode but for some reason it isnt doing much of anything

Comment: Why have you removed JQquery? Coudl you share a piece of HTML code where you embed your scripts?

Comment: @MaksymPolshcha if you read my question you would see why i removed the jquery include line... to see if it in fact was some sort of conflict. and i think it is due to the fact it works without the WHMCS jquery file and with only mine on it. but if i remove the WHMCS jquery file it breaks the whmcs navbar and domain checker along with the whole WHMCS layout. I wont be pasting the source as its quite alot. Heres the link to the page though so you can see the page source. http://ccp.hyped-design.info/clientarea.php